# Maximum number of certificates generated (Distribution)

Tags: ios, certificate

**How to create new Distribution Certificate?**

In Apple Developer Account I faced below error.

I deleted a certificate(Development).

But I still get this error.

[image]

Apple Distribution Certificates is always gray...
[image]

Comment: The development certificates are different from distribution certificates. So delete development certificates don't help in this case.
A maximum of 3 app store and Ad Hoc production certificates can be active at the same time for the Apple Developer program. For Enterprise it’s 2 certificates.

Comment: Oh. I have 3 Distribution certificate. Thank you nghiahoang!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After 24 hours I managed to create the certificate again. Here it happened to have 3 mobile devs in the team, and my certificate would expire soon. I revoked the certificate and kept this lock to create a new one for 24 hours. Apparently for security reasons, apple takes this period to free up a space.